# Twilio - Call another person during a call and setup a conference call

Tags: twilio, conference

I'm using Twilio to build a service right now. Here's my use case:

In a web page, I input a phone number and call it using Twilio JS (already done). During the call, I want to input another number and call another person. The call with the first person will be forwarded to the conference. When the second person answer the call, he will join the conference too.

Is it possible to use Twilio to implement this case?

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible with twilio. i have worked on that scenario directly and twilio api works excellently well.

When u initiate a call from the twilio number to the first number, use the call back url to connect the person to the another person you want.
This can be done using twiML, which has `<Dial>` which will be of great help to you.
This is the easiest way of implementation.

The other way, is pretty clean but takes time to implement.
The twilio api provides conference capability themselves.
So you can create a request of conference with all the numbers that need to be connected.
The down side of this is that, all number will be called and connected, if your requirement is to call the first number and then only connect him to another person, then i wouldnt recommend this solution.

I hope this helped you.